# How do I use tie downs on a trailer?

Tags: moving, vehicle

I have a box trailer 8 x 5 foot with a 3 foot cage.

I'm not sure how I should be securing loads. (I'm using it to buy hay, both small bales and round bales (a round bale will be 4 foot diameter and 4 foot high). The small square bales will fit within the cage.

While this may be a basic question for some people, it's not so easy to find good suggestions about how to do it.

I've been looking through my local hardware at [tie downs and load restraints](https://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range/building-hardware/general-hardware/tie-down-load-restraints).

Can anyone give me some advice on how to use ties to tie down my load?

Comment: I have no idea if this is on topic, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 obvious ways:

1) Ratchet straps. This is the easy way, requiring very little in the way of skill or knowledge - I use them a lot. Here in the UK you can get them for £1-£2 each and 2 should be enough for what you're carrying I think. They are very self-explanatory once you get one in your hands so there's not much point in trying to explain how to use them here.

2) Use a rope and a "Trucker's Hitch". If you're good with knots this is better than a ratchet strap. Search "Trucker's Hitch" on Youtube to find many people explaining how to use it.

Comment: My husband and I bought hay for years and used ratchet straps. Note that you want to center the majority of the weight over the axels.